# Have these polynomials been studied? (Perhaps as generalizations of Schur polynomials in vector variables?)

Tags: reference-request, determinants, toric-varieties, symmetric-polynomials, schur-functions

For $n\geq 3$, let $\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_n \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ be a collection of points in the plane with integer coordinates $\mathbf{a}_i = (a_{1i},a_{2i})$ where each $a_{1i} > 0$. For each $i,j$, let
$$
    d_{ij}  =   |\mathbf{a}_i, \; \mathbf{a}_j|
            =   a_{1i} a_{2j} - a_{1j} a_{2i}
$$
denote the determinant of the corresponding $2\times 2$ matrix. I'm studying the following rational function (all indices range from $1$ to $n$ with the given constraints):
$$
    F       =   \sum\limits_{i,j : d_{ij} > 0} \quad
                \frac{d_{ij}^{2n - 5}}
                    {\prod\limits_{k\neq i,j} (d_{ij} - d_{ik} - d_{jk})
                     (d_{ij} + d_{ik} + d_{jk})}.
$$
Combining the terms, $F$ can be expressed as a rational function with numerator
$$
  \sum\limits_{i,j:d_{ij} > 0} \; d_{ij}^{2n - 5}
    \prod\limits_{\substack{p,q,r:d_{pq}, d_{qr} > 0 \\
          \{p,q,r\}\not\supset\{i,j\}}}
      (d_{pq} + d_{pr} + d_{qr})
    \prod\limits_{\substack{p,q,r:d_{pq}, d_{qr} > 0 \\ r\neq j}}
      (d_{qr} + d_{qp} + d_{rp})
     \prod\limits_{\substack{p,q,r:d_{pq}, d_{qr} > 0 \\ p\neq i}}
      (d_{pq} - d_{pr} - d_{qr})
$$
and denominator
$$
  \prod\limits_{p,q,r:d_{pq}, d_{qr} > 0}
   (d_{pq} + d_{pr} + d_{qr})(d_{qr} + d_{qp} + d_{rp})
   (d_{pq} - d_{pr} - d_{qr}).
$$
I expect (and have verified for some small $n$) that the denominator factors $(d_{qr} + d_{qp} + d_{rp})$ and $(d_{pq} - d_{pr} - d_{qr})$ cancel, i.e. this can be expressed as
$$
    F = \frac{S}{\prod\limits_{p,q,r:d_{pq}, d_{qr} > 0}
               (d_{pq} + d_{pr} + d_{qr})}
$$
for some polynomial $S$ in the $d_{ij}$. Note that (for $n > 3$) these cancellations do **not** occur if we consider $F$ as a rational function of the free variables $d_{ij}$. The $d_{ij}$ satisfy relations (the Plücker relations), and so the cancellations only occur if you express the $d_{ij}$ in terms of the $a_{pq}$ or otherwise apply the relations. Hence, as a polynomial in the $d_{ij}$, $S$ is not unique.

> Does anyone know of a reference or context where polynomials like these have been studied? I expect that they have been but have been unable to find a reference. Ideally, I'd like to understand:
>
> - A reason for the cancellations, e.g., an interpretation or property of the numerator of $F$ that explains why they occur, and
> - A combinatorial interpretation for the resulting numerator $S$, including a ``standard representation" of $S$ (e.g. with positive coefficients or some similar constraint).
>
> But any suggestion of related work, a reference for the theory of polynomials in variables $d_{ij}$ with Plücker relations, or similar cancellations in the presence of these relations would be appreciated.

It may help to note that this arises in a generalization of a situation where the $\mathbf{a}_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}^2$. In that case, the numerator of $F$ is a determinant, the cancelling factors in the denominator are the Vandermonde determinant, so the resulting numerator $S$ is a Schur polynomial (explaining the title).

Comment: Have you made any progress on this question?

Comment: Not much, but I have a student working on them at the moment.